# Как передать переменную окружения в код?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

Есть переменная окружения VAR. Нужно условно компилировать часть кода, если только эта переменная определена. Само значение переменной не важно. Я пробую сделать так

```
#ifdef VAR
    // Здесь пошел мой код
#endif
```

но препроцессор не видит VAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сборка идет через make, можно добавить ключ в флаги

```
ifdef VAR
    CFLAGS +=-DVAR
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Передавай с ключом -D, вот таким образом:

```
gcc -DVAR somefile.c
```

По крайней мере так передаются препроцессору переменные. Насчет того, можно ли таким образом сделать условную компиляцию - не уверен

Answer (score 0):

В случае bash можно 
gcc `case ${VAR}x in x) echo "";; *) echo -DVAR;; esac` somefile.c